# i want backgroud image full screen but background image not responsive and it split head of backgroud image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

what should i do if i want to responsive image and full image in screen? because i'm just start with **tailwindcss**.

```
<div class="w-full h-screen bg-violet-300">
       <div class="flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center bg-center absolute bottom-0" style="background-image:url('../static/img/bg.png')"></div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wre8o.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking out for `object-cover` property

Using `object-cover`

```
<div class="w-full min-h-screen bg-violet-300">
       <img class=" h-screen w-full object-cover  " src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.4XB8NF1awQyApnQDDmBmQwHaEo?pid=ImgDet&rs=1"></div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Using `object-contain`

```
<div class="w-full min-h-screen bg-violet-300">
       <img class=" h-screen w-full object-contain  " src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.4XB8NF1awQyApnQDDmBmQwHaEo?pid=ImgDet&rs=1"></div>
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

---

**Edit:**

If you want to avoid `img` you can use `bg` class in the div and set `bg-cover` property .

```
<div class="min-h-screen w-full bg-violet-300">
  <div class=" h-screen bg-[url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.4XB8NF1awQyApnQDDmBmQwHaEo?pid=ImgDet&rs=1')] bg-cover"></div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]
`bg-contain`

```
<div class="min-h-screen w-full bg-violet-300">
  <div class=" h-screen bg-[url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.4XB8NF1awQyApnQDDmBmQwHaEo?pid=ImgDet&rs=1')] bg-contain bg-no-repeat"></div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: have any way to use without img tag?